# Counterexamples Of The Infinite Dimensional Linear Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite dimensional linear spaces over the field $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathscr{A} :V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map between  $V$ and $W$.  Then we have

1. $\mathscr{A}$ is an injective linear map if and only if there exists a linear map $\mathscr{B}:W\rightarrow V$ such that $\mathscr{BA}=\mathit{Id}_{\mathbf{V}}$. ($\mathit{Id}_{\mathbf{V}}$ is the identity map on $V$)
2. $\mathscr{A}$ is a surjective
   linear map if and only if there exists a linear map $\mathscr{C}:W\rightarrow V$ such that $\mathscr{AC}=\mathit{Id}_{\mathbf{W}}$.

I think that 1 and 2 above don't hold if $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional linear spaces over $\mathbb{F}$.

I need some counterexamples to verify my idea. How can I find them?

Comment: Just define them on a basis as you would do for finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Ennar:You mean both $(3)$ and $(4)$ are right conclusions?

Comment: Sure. If you throw in norm (or other topology) on your vector spaces, then I'm not sure anymore if you can immediately get continuity (or at all).

Comment: This could be helpful to apply Ennar's suggestion : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351848/how-to-prove-there-exists-a-unique-linear-map-such-that-te-i-w-i-in-an-inf

Comment: Note however, that the argument suggested by @Ennar only applies if you are willing to use the axiom of choice, which is needed to get the standard results on bases needed to do this in infinite dimensions. This also implies that it is impossible to construct explicit counter examples.

Comment: @Andreas is right since "every vector space has a basis" is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Ennar:Ah, they are really  right !  I miss some simple conceptions  that can generalize from finite to infinite !  Thanks    for your reminder !

Comment: user553010, if you know about free objects (like free groups), just think of vector spaces as free modules.

Comment: @AndreasCap:Maybe we need Zorn Lemma.@Ennar: Oh, modules－ the concept is advanced for me now.but  your hint give me some inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

#### Exercise (1):

$\Leftarrow$: Assume $A$ was not injective, i.e. we had $v, v'$ with $Av = Av'$. Then $BAv = v = v' = BAv'$, which is a contradiction.

$\Rightarrow$: Define the linear map $B: Im(A) \to V$ by

$$B(w) \in A^{-1}(w)$$

for every $w \in Im(A)$. This definition is unique and well-defined since $A$ is injective.
$B$ is as the (effective) inverse of a linear map also linear.

Extend $B$ from the subspace $Im(A)$ to $W$ linearly. Then obviously $BAv = B(Av) = v$ by definition.

You can indeed extend $B$ linearly by noting that within vector spaces every subspace has a complement (e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713561/existence-of-vector-space-complement-and-axiom-of-choice)): There is a subspace $M$, so that $W = Im(A) \oplus M$.
Now define $B': W \to V$ by $B'(w) = B'(x + y) := B(x) + 0$ with $x \in Im(A)$ and $y \in M$.

**Alternative:** Let $\{v_i | i \in I\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then $N := \{Av_i | i \in I\}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors as well:

$$0 = \sum_k \alpha_k Av_k \Rightarrow A^{-1}0 = A^{-1} \sum_k \alpha_k Av_k \Rightarrow 0 = \sum_k \alpha_k v_k \Rightarrow \forall k. \alpha_k = 0$$

Extend $N$ to a basis of $W$, namely $N \cup \{w_j | j \in J\}$ and define $B: W \to V$ using [Ennar's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937812/counterexamples-of-the-infinite-dimensional-linear-space#comment6068576_2937812)
 by its image on the basis elements: $B(Av_i) = v_i$ and $B(w_j) = 0$ (arbitrary).

Then $BAv = BA(\sum_k \alpha_k v_k) = \sum_k \alpha_k B(Av_k) = \sum_k \alpha_k v_k = v$ as required.

#### Exercise (2)

$\Leftarrow$: $AC = Id_W$ directly implies that $A$ is surjective.

$\Rightarrow$: Again, using [Ennar's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937812/counterexamples-of-the-infinite-dimensional-linear-space#comment6068576_2937812)
, Define the linear map $C: W \to V$ by $$C(w_i) \in A^{-1}(w_i).$$
Then $ACw = AC(\sum \beta_j w_j) = \sum \beta_j ACw_j = \sum \beta_j w_j = w.$

Comment: Since $Im(A)\subset W$,$W$ instead of $V$ in $V = Im(A) \oplus M$ should be right.Obviously,It was just a slip of the open. Your answer expressed what I meant  to say.+1

Comment: @user553010 Thanks! It's now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In the language of category theory, for a division ring $\mathbb{F}$, every object in the abelian category $\mathcal{C}:=\mathbf{Vec}(\mathbb{F})$ of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces and $\mathbb{F}$-linear maps is both injective and projective.  That is, any exact sequence $$0\to A \to B\to C\to 0$$ of objects and morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ splits.  In other words, the morphism $A\to B$ has a left inverse $B\to A$, the morphism $B\to C$ has a right inverse $C\to B$, and $B\cong A\oplus C$.  The proof relies on the Axiom of Choice in creating a basis, or extending a linearly independent subset to a basis of a vector space.

How does this solve your problem?  Well, if $\mathscr{A}:V\to W$ is an injective map, then there exists a short exact sequence
$$0\to V\overset{\mathscr{A}}{\longrightarrow} W \to W/\text{im}(\mathscr{A})\to 0\,,$$
which splits, whence there exists a left inverse $W\overset{\mathscr{B}}{\longrightarrow} V$ of $\mathscr{A}$, making $\mathscr{B}\circ\mathscr{A}=\text{id}_V$.  If $\mathscr{A}:V\to W$ is a surjective map, then there exists a short exact sequence
$$0\to \ker(\mathscr{A}) \to V\overset{\mathscr{A}}{\longrightarrow}  W\to 0\,,$$
which splits, whence there exists a right inverse $W\overset{\mathscr{C}}{\longrightarrow} V$ of $\mathscr{A}$, making $\mathscr{A}\circ\mathscr{C}=\text{id}_W$.